# How to use greek letters as labels in curve3d()?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot the expression `1.3*x+4*y` as follows:

```
curve3d(1.3*x+4*y,zlabel="${{{\varepsilon }'}_{r}}$")
```

where ${{{\varepsilon }'}_{r}}$ is the latex code of the Greek symbol "epsilon" supplied with "prime" and subscripted with "r". Could anybody help me in how to perform it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which package is `curve3d` from? You can probably use `plotmath` for the labels. See the documentation.